# Image classifier Keras predict

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I follow a tutorial present on Keras blog and I have the following problem: Once the model is trained, how can I pick a image and classify it?

I know that the *train_generator.class_indices* have the classes in the model.

The goal is to introduce the path of an image and returns the corresponding class.

Here is the code:

```python
#libraries used

from keras import backend as K
from keras import applications
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

import cv2

from PIL import Image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.misc import imread

import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 3000
nb_validation_samples = 1200
epochs = 10 #50
batch_size = 16

n_classes = 3

# Get data

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height),\
                                                batch_size=batch_size,class_mode = 'categorical') # class_mode='binary'

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height),\
                                                    batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical') #class_mode = 'categorical


if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax')) #sigmoid

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy']) #loss binary_crossentropy
# on the other model
#model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
epochs=epochs,validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps = nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

**Edit 1:**

I wrote the following function and it doesn't work:

```python
def predict(model, img, target_size):
    if img.size != target_size:
        img = img.resize(target_size)

    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    preds = model.predict(x)
    return preds[0]


target_size = (150, 150)
model = load_model(model_name)

img_path = 'image_test/test1.jpg'
img = Image.open(img_path)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
preds = predict(model, img, target_size)
preds
```

**Edit 2**:

Error presented:

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-516f01bf49e9> in <module>()
     17 plt.imshow(img)
     18 plt.show()
---> 19 preds = predict(model, img, target_size)
     20 preds

<ipython-input-55-516f01bf49e9> in predict(model, img, target_size)
      3         img = img.resize(target_size)
      4 
----> 5     x = image.img_to_array(img)
      6     x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
      7     x = preprocess_input(x)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'img_to_array'
```

**EDIT 3**: The solution is the following (we must reshape the figure):

```python
def predict(model, img, target_size):
    if img.size != target_size:
        img = img.resize(target_size)

    x = img.getdata() #.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = (x/255.)
    print("shape = ", x.shape)
    x = x.reshape(1,150,150,3)
    preds = model.predict(x)
    return preds[0]


target_size = (150, 150)

img_path = 'image_test/bird.jpg'
img = Image.open(img_path)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
preds = predict(model, img, target_size)
preds
```

Comment: You mean that `model.predict(image)` will not work?

Comment: I made and Edit in my post.

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get an error or is the prediction not what you expect?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get from the generator the exact shape expected by your model:

```
X, Y = train_generator.next()  #or next(train_generator)
```

Now see these:

```
print(X.shape)
print(X.max())
```

Get an image library, such as Pillow (`from PIL import Image`), for instance, and load the files you want into an array (the method depends on the library).

Make sure that the maximum in this loaded array is compatible with the maximum in `X` (you may have to divide the array by 255, for instance)

You may create an array with several images, or just an image, but make sure the batch size is considered in the first dimension:

```
oneImageBatch = oneImageArray.reshape((1,)+oneImageArray.shape)
```

And then use `model.predict(oneImageBatch)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for sure.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

targ_size = (150, 150)

def predict(model, img_path):
    x = image.load_image(img_path, target_size=targ_size)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    preds = model.predict(x)
    return preds


model = load_model(model_name)
img_path = 'image_test/test1.jpg'
preds = predict(model, img_path)
```

This will return an array of probabilities for each class. If you want to know which class it is, just do this:

`pred_class = np.argmax(pred, axis=-1)`